# Group By clause Issue when using case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to sum up volumes across the year for every distinct **sender** and have the years as fields. I am using a case statement to do this.

```
select distinct sender,
  case
    when extract(month from (month)) = 1
      then sum(volume)
  end as January,
  case
    when  extract(month from (month)) = 2
      then sum(volume)
  end as February,
  case
    when extract(month from (month)) = 3
      then sum(volume)
  end as March
from [lifetime_data]
group by 1
```

When i run this i get an error that asks me to group by month, Month is not one of the columns i am selecting, i am only using it in my condition... how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation -- the `case` expression is an argument to the `sum()`:

```
select sender,
       sum(case when extract(month from (month)) = 1 then volume end) as January,
       sum(case when extract(month from (month)) = 2 then volume end) as February,
       sum(case when extract(month from (month)) = 3 then volume end) as March
from [lifetime_data]
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because your case statement is running row by row hence o/p for each row doesnt match the group of each row. Try the below

```
   Select sender, 
  extract(month from (month)), 
    SUM(Volume) from table group by
     sender, 
  extract(month from (month)) having
    extract(month from (month)) IN 
      (1,2,3)
```